# I need to enable Subversion integration on every branch

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

Whenever I start working on a new branch, I need to re-enable subversion integration (Version Control --> Enable Version Control Integration).

This is a fresh installation of IntelliJ, and I don't remember this phenomenon in previous times I installed it. Am I missing some global configuration?

Answer (score 0):

That may be related to [issue IDEA-22583](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-22583?query=jdk):

> If I have project A open with Subversion version control everything works perfectly. If I close project A and open project B (or open project B in the same frame) then project B correctly recognizes the subversion details. However, if I open project A and then open project B in a new frame (so that both projects are open) then project B loses all ability to recognize the files as subversion files.

Check also the exact version of subversion you are using (as [detailled in DOC-1145](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1145))